# MultiThreading Python Issue(Segmentation fault)

Tags: python, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run the following code in multithreading however I keep getting the " Segmentation fault      (core dumped)" . Please advise what I am doing wrong -

```
def insert_api(r):
    url = url_responses+'/'+str(r[0])
    response = requests.get(url,headers={'api-key':APIToken,'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    if response.status_code == 200:
        dd = json.loads(response.content)
        InsertTable('API_Response',str(r[0]),str(r[1]),json.dumps(dd['result']))        
    else:
        logMsg('','HTTP request for '+url_responses+' failed. HTTP response code is: '+str(response.status_code),'failure')
        subject='API Request failed *********                  '+ datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
        Body='This email is to notify that the API request for the URL: ' +str(url)+' failed at '+ datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
        email_notifier(subject,Body)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(insert_api,response_list)
```

InsertTable is a function to insert records in a table(API_Response) passed as parameter along with other values. email_notifier is a function to send emails in case of exceptions. Since I have 95k+ records in the API , hence trying to implement the multithreading logic.

Thanks
Samy!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by adding a lock logic before my InsertTable function

Comment: Can you share an example of how you resolved this? I'm doing almost identical routine, and getting "Segmentation Fault" after a random amount of time. I'm also saving records to a database, so wondering if it may be the same issue as yours.

Comment: Yeah, your answer does not add any information...